# '(String) -> AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'ResultCell'​

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I am trying to cast my own custom cell but is seems not to be working, I am new at IOS and swift dev... From the tutorial I was watching it works fine but when I try, It gives me an error.
 Here are the codes.

```
class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var resultTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let height = view.frame.height
    let width = view.frame.width

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : ResultCell = UITableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as ResultCell

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
// Deactivate the return button 
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}


 }
```

and this is the cell I created

```
  class ResultCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ContactprofilePic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var contactUserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contactStatus: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let aWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, aWidth, 120)

    ContactprofilePic.center = CGPointMake(60, 60)
    ContactprofilePic.layer.cornerRadius = ContactprofilePic.frame.size.width/2
    ContactprofilePic.clipsToBounds = true

    contactUserName.center = CGPointMake(230, 55)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

  }
```

but then I am getting this error

> (String) -> AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'ResultCell'

Comment: Is it a compile time or a run time error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UITableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...)
```

should be

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...)
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` is an instance method and must
be called on the `tableView` instance which is passed as first
parameter to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

---

Actually the expression

```
UITableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
```

*is valid*, as explained in http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/. The value of this expression is a
"curried function" of the type

```
(UITableView) -> (String) -> AnyObject?
```

This is most probably not what you intended to do, but explains the
error message

```
(String) -> AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'ResultCell'
```